# Invite Facebook friends through iPhone App using FBWebDialogs

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios7

I am using Facebook sdk 3.10 to send a request to multiple friend at a time using `FBWebDialogs`. Following code I'm using and all thing is fine like selecting multiple friends , sending them request. But there is one problem, is this FBWebDialogs uses some limit of friends as I have more that 300 friends but this is showing only 12-15 friends always.

**CODE**

```
[FBWebDialogs
             presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
             message:@"Learn how to make your iOS apps social."
             title:nil
             parameters:nil
             handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                 if (error) {
                     // Error launching the dialog or sending the request.
                     NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
                 } else {
                     if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                         // User clicked the "x" icon
                         NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                     } else {
                         // Handle the send request callback
                         NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
                         if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"request"]) {
                             // User clicked the Cancel button
                             NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                         } else {
                             // User clicked the Send button
                             NSString *requestID = [urlParams valueForKey:@"request"];
                             NSLog(@"Request ID: %@", requestID);
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }];
```

Using above I can see only max 12 friends in the dialog? Am I missing something?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you found any solution ? I am facing the same problem it works well for 20-30 friends but above that it will auto clost the dialog with FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted result !

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the `NSDictionary` type object to parameters argument.
You can create like this:

```
NSArray *suggestedFriends = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"fb_id1", @"fb_id2", nil];

NSMutableDictionary* params =   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[suggestedFriends componentsJoinedByString:@","], @"suggestions", nil];
```

Now

```
[FBWebDialogs
             presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
             message:@"Learn how to make your iOS apps social."
             title:nil
             parameters:params
             handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                 if (error) {
                     // Error launching the dialog or sending the request.
                     NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
                 } else {
                     if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                         // User clicked the "x" icon
                         NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                     } else {
                         // Handle the send request callback
                         NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
                         if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"request"]) {
                             // User clicked the Cancel button
                             NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                         } else {
                             // User clicked the Send button
                             NSString *requestID = [urlParams valueForKey:@"request"];
                             NSLog(@"Request ID: %@", requestID);
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }];
```

Here it will show all of the friends with the suggested Facebook ids.